# Flutter Project, Firebase Login not working And throwing Unhandled Exception: type 'FirebaseUser' is not a subtype of type 'bool' Error

Tags: firebase, flutter

[Firebase Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MKB6B.png)

Pubspec.yaml *(Firebase Versions using in App)*

---

firebase_core: ^0.4.4+3
   firebase_auth: ^0.16.0

Build.gradle *(Google Services Version in App)*

---

classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'

**Authservice.dart**

```
Future signInAnon() async {
    try {
      ***below line is throwing error***
      AuthResult result = await _auth.signInAnonymously();
      FirebaseUser user = result.user;
      print(user);
      return user;
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
      return e;
    }
  }
```

**Signin.dart widget**

```
onPressed: () async {
 dynamic result = await _auth.signInAnon();
   if(!result) {
     print('Signin');
       print(result);
     } else {
       print('Error While You Signin');
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`signInAnon` returns a `FirebaseUser` object.

But you are checking `if` condition using a `boolen`. Thats why you are getting error. Instead do `null` check. Try this :

```
onPressed: () async {
 var result = await _auth.signInAnon();
   if(result != null) {
     // your code
   } else {
     // error code
   }
 }
```

Comment: After changing the code based on your suggestion, I'm getting result value as FirebaseUser(Instance of 'PlatformUser'). I'm expecting user details.

Comment: Anonymous login, firebase will not written the object. 
print(result) // output: FirebaseUser(Instance of 'PlatformUser').
print(result.uid) // output: prints uid.

Your solution working and thanks for your help.

Comment: Glad that it helps.